# How to organise abstract class hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I have a situation in C# when I need multiple inheritance in order to not double code in implementation class, but that's forbidden in C#.

What should I do?

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface ICar
{
   void Move();
   void GetService();
}

public interface ISuperCar : ICar
{
   void MoveFast();
   void HaveARace();
}
```

And abstract classes:

```
public abstract class Car : ICar
{
   public void Move()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Car moves");
   }

   public abstract void GetService();
}

public abstract class SuperCar : Car, ISuperCar
{
   public void MoveFast()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("SuperCar moves fastly");
   }

   public abstract void HaveARace();
}
```

And their implementations:

```
public class ToyotaCar : Car
{
   public override void GetService()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Getting ToyotaService");
   }
}

public class ToyotaSuperCar : SuperCar
{
   public override void GetService()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Getting ToyotaService");
   }

   public override void HaveARace()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Have a race in Toyota competition");
   }
}
```

And the question is how not to double method *GetService()*. Logically it should by:

```
public class ToyotaSuperCar : SuperCar, ToyotaCar
{
   public override void HaveARace()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Have a race in Toyota competition");
   }
}
```

But multiple inheritance is not available in C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use composition instead of inheritance. Make your `SuperCar` class implement `ICar` instead of inheriting from `Car` and pass an `ICar` object in the constructor to which you delegate the methods:

```
public abstract class SuperCar : ICar, ISuperCar
{
    private readonly ICar car;

    public SuperCar(ICar car)
    {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void Move() => car.Move();

    public void GetService() => car.GetService();

    public void MoveFast()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SuperCar moves fastly");
    }

   public abstract void HaveARace();
}
```

Your `ToyotaSuperCar` class would then look like so:

```
public class ToyotaSuperCar : SuperCar
{
    public ToyotaSuperCar(ToyotaCar car) : base(car) { }

    public override void HaveARace()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Have a race in Toyota competition");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
public class SuperCarPart : Car, ISuperCar
{
    public override void GetService() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void HaveARace() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void MoveFast() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class ToyotaSuperCar : ToyotaCar, ISuperCar
{
    private SuperCarPart _superCarPart = new SuperCarPart();
    public void HaveARace()
    {
        _superCarPart.HaveARace();
    }

    public void MoveFast()
    {
        _superCarPart.MoveFast();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to declare service as its own interface

```cs
public interface ICarService
{
    void CarryOutService();
}
```

The car interfaces then look like this:

```cs
public interface ICar
{
    ICarService Service { get; }
    void Move();
}

public interface ISuperCar : ICar
{
    void MoveFast();
    void HaveARace();
}
```

The abstract classes need a constructor having a `ICarService` parameter.

```cs
public abstract class Car : ICar
{
    public Car(ICarService service) => Service = service;

    public ICarService Service { get; }

    public void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car moves");
    }
}

public abstract class SuperCar : Car, ISuperCar
{
    public SuperCar(ICarService service)
        : base(service)
    {
    }

    public void MoveFast()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SuperCar moves fast");
    }

    public abstract void HaveARace();
}
```

A possible implementation of a service:

```cs
public class ToyotaService : ICarService
{
    public void CarryOutService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Carrying out ToyotaService");
    }
}
```

In the concrete implementations of the cars you have the choice to either pass the service in the constructors or to instantiate them directly. Since a Toyota will always have a `ToyotaService` you can instantiate them directly. For more flexibility use the constructor approach.

```cs
public class ToyotaCar : Car
{
    public ToyotaCar()
        : base(new ToyotaService())
    {
    }
}

public class ToyotaSuperCar : SuperCar
{
    public ToyotaSuperCar()
        : base(new ToyotaService())
    {
    }

    public override void HaveARace()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Have a race in Toyota competition");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var car = new ToyotaSuperCar();
car.Service.CarryOutService();
```

We followed the [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle here. It has the additional advantage that it becomes easier to extend the service interface in future, since this does not impact the implementation of the cars.